# Native JavaScript Another HTML element value not changing when radio trigger event is changed

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener

It's been more than a week I was stuck with not changing another HTML element

```
<input class="type_val" type="hidden" name="frm_english_type[]" value="">
```

when radio selection is changed.

```
<input type="radio" class="js-english-input" name="english_type" value="American English">
<input type="radio" class="js-english-input" name="english_type" value="British/Australian English">
```

I only use native JavaScript, nothing else for event handling.

```
var type_val = frm_english_types[y].querySelector('.type_val');
                var temp = '';
                english_inputs[x].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                    temp = this.value;
                    //console.log(e.target.value);
                    type_val.setAttribute('value', temp);
                    console.log('Applying change: ' + temp);
                    /*var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                    evt.initEvent("change", true, true);
                    type_val.dispatchEvent(evt);*/

                    var event = new Event('load');
                    type_val.dispatchEvent(event);

                    console.log(type_val);
                });
```

Could anyone find what's wrong with my codes?

Comment: try changing temp = this.value; to temp = english_inputs[x].value;

Comment: It says 'undefined'

Comment: Okay, i just changed the code to this `english_inputs[x].onclick = (e) => {
     var type_val = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.type_val');
     temp = e.target.value;
     type_val.value = temp;
    };`.  With this line `var type_val = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.type_val');` I just call the parent of the parent of that selected element (i.e. the "grandfather") and worked